# Why 'Is Kinematics' works different on HoloLens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, rigid-bodies, mrtk

**Overview**
I wanted to have a cube, that I can drag around the scene with the components `Collider`, `Rigidbody` and `ObjectManipulator`. In play mode everything works fine, but running it on the hololens, the cube starts flying around after dragging it a few time.
**Steps to reproduce** (All components are set via editor, not via code)

1. Create new project and set it up for AR/HoloLens
2. Import MRTK 2.4
3. Create cube with a `Box Collider`. Set `Is Trigger = true`
4. Add `Rigidbody` to cube. Set `Use Gravity = false` and `Is Kinematic = true`
5. Add `Object Manipulator` to cube. I have a method getting called after `On Manipulation Ended`, but don't know if thats important.

**Expected behavior**
The rigidbody is set to `Is Kinematic = true` and `Use Gravity = false`, so that the cube stays still/stops moving after releasing dragging it. This works while trying it inside the unity play mode. But running it on the hololens, the cube behaves like `Is Kinematic = false` and starts flying around after interacting with it. Sometimes after the second drag and sometimes after the third time drag.

**Error**
Before updating this post, I didnt noticed the development console in left corner of my hololens. At the beginng of the scene I get the message `[Physics.PhysX] BV4 midphase only supported on intel platforms` but at that moment everything is fine. As the cube begins to fly around I get the a `NullReferenceExeption: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Comment: It should work on HoloLens as well as on Unity Editor. There is nothing magical in Kinematics at all. Could you reproduce this issue on another Unity Project? If it did reproduce, please provide an MVCE(stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can locate the issue or find a solution.

Comment: Which Unity version you are using? I try to reproduce your issue with Unity 2019.4.1f1 and HoloLens1 but failed. For your [Physics.PhysX] issue, I find that the fix has  been merged into 2019.4.1f1: https://forum.unity.com/threads/physx-4-1-in-unity-experimental-builds.634960/page-6#post-5966804 If you are using a lower version of Unity, please upgrade your Unity and try it again.

Comment: I'm using Unity 2019.4.8f1, but for the new project I used 2019.3.14f, thats why I got the physics-message. Nevertheless the cube starts flying in both versions, after dragging it around in the scene. Did you drag the cube several times? Because sometimes it happens at the first grab and sometimes I have to grab it more times.

Comment: Yes, I have grab it several times, and it always works fine.  If you are using HoloLens2 with Unity ARM64 build, it is possible an unknown issue from the Unity side.  Recommend checking with the forums for Unity or feedback this issue to Unity.

Comment: Today I noticed, at which process my issue happens. Did you set your box collider 'IsTrigger = true'? Because I forgot that today and noticed that I can drag the cube without losing the reference. But the problem was that I collided with my mesh and could not overlapp it. So I changed my 'IsTrigger' to true and the cube started to lose the reference and fly around.

Comment: Yes, the `IsTrigger` checkbox has been set to true, but I still can't reproduce your issue. I followed all your steps but no method was called after `On Manipulation Ended`, however it works fine. From this, we can try to narrow it down to your own code part. Could you provide your method which getting called after `On Manipulation Ended`?

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT I found the problem, it was the method getting called by 'OnManipulationEnded'. I posted it as an answer. Now I dont know how to rename the title of my question, according to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue. I know the approximate cause, but I do not fully understand it. The method, getting called after `OnManipulationEnded` caused that.

1. I have a list, getting filled and drained by OnTriggerEnter/-Exit (exit looks the same, except add→remove):

   ```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
    if (other.gameObject.layer != 31) return;
    _objectsCollidingWith.Add(other.gameObject);}
   ```
2. OnManipulationEnded triggered this method:

   ```
    private int GetMeshes(List<KeyValuePair<Transform, Mesh>> transMeshes){
    foreach (GameObject go in _objectsCollidingWith)
    {
        transMeshes.Add(new KeyValuePair<Transform, Mesh>(go.transform , go.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh));
    }
    return transMeshes.Count;}
   ```

So I got alot of nullreferences from `GetMeshes`, because some gameobject in the list `_objectsCollidingWith` were null. Thats because the mesh is getting updated every once in a while. That caused a lot of nullreferences until the cube just flew away.
I used the whole time the logging provider via the device portal and couldnt see what is causing this errors. But after running the project via holographic emulation I could see in the console where they were coming from.
**How did I fixed my problem?**
I found this [post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/fix-ontriggerexit-will-now-be-called-for-disabled-gameobjects-colliders.657205/) because I realized that my `OnTriggerExit` didn't get called and cased having null objects and some spatial meshes with the same name triggered `OnTriggerEnter` very often. Also I added this line in the foreach loop in `GetMeshes` because once in a while there is still a null object:

```
if (go == null)
  continue;
```

**PS:** Please forgive the strange code formatting, somehow the editor here on so does not allow me to place the brackets somewhere else